# Pass key values from 2 dictionaries to xml payload using python

Tags: python, xml, payload

I want to pass key values from 2 different dictionaries to payload.

```
dict1 =  {'Name1': 'username1', 'Name2': 'username2'}
dict2 =  {'Name1': 'id1', 'Name2': 'id2'}
```

This is my payload-

```
payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<BES xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"BES.xsd\">\r\n <UserName> {} </UserName>\r\n <UserID Name=\"id\"> {} </UserID >\r\n</BES>\r\n"


headers = {
    'Authorization': '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
}

response = requests.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, data=payload.format(dict1(username), dict2(id)))
```

There will be more Names. How should I go about this?

Comment: What is the dict? you want to call the api with `(username1, id1) , (username2, id2)` like that?

Comment: Yes, that's right..

Comment: check the answer if it answers your question